# Text become bold when the cursor hovers a drop-down menu button?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, mouseover

When I move the cursor on different elements of the list in the <*nav*>, everything gets bold..
Source: http://htv2.tumblr.com
Video: http://quick.as/9gdcozz

> ```
>    nav {width:100%;height:70px;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;background:#0c1d37;z-index:999;}
>     .title {margin:5px 50px;color:#fff;float:left;}
>     .title h1 {font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;font-size:2em;line-height:1.4em;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;padding-right:15px;}
>     .title h2 {font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;font-size:1.0em;font-weight:300;font-style:italic;margin-top:-32px;line-height:1.8em;}
>     .menunav {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size:0.9em;line-height:0.9em;font-weight:300;font-style:italic;text-transform:uppercase;position:relative;}
>     .menunav ul {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
>     .menunav ul li {display:inline-block;width:100px;height:70px;text-align:center;line-height:70px;cursor:pointer;}
>     .menunav ul li:hover {background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);}
>     .menunav a {font-weight:300;color:#fff;}
>     .menunav ul li div.showmenav {display:none;}
>     .menunav ul li.contacts:hover > div.showmenav {display:list-item;position:absolute;}
>     .showmenav {background:#0c1d37;width:100px;overflow:visible;}
>     ul.dropdown li {display:list-item;text-align:center;}
>     div.menunav a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
> ```

---

```
<body>
<nav><div class="wrapmobile"><div class="title"><h1>{Title}</h1><br/>{block:Description}<h2>{Description}</h2>{/block:Description}</div></div>
<div class="menunav">
    <ul>
        <a href="/"><li class="home">Home</li></a>
        <a href="/me"><li class="about">About</li></a>
        <li class="contacts">Contacts
            <div class="showmenav">
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/"><li>Twitter</li></a>
                    <a href="/ask"><li>Ask</li></a>
                    <a href="/"><li>Skype</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>    
        </li>
        <li class="search"><a href="/archive">History</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Just a note - your HTML is invalid.  You need to switch the nesting of your `<li>` and `<a>` tags.  Should be `<li><a href="...">Twitter</a></li>`

Comment: I wanted to extend the link-area on the button and seems to work.. Any suggestions..?

Comment: Extending the link area can still be done with correct HTML code. I can't see your font becoming bold on hover on the link you gave.

Comment: Here: http://quick.as/9gdcozz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your anchor tag inside of your list items and try adding a font-weight of 300 to the anchor tag's hover pseudo element. It looks like the font-weight of your anchor tags are set to less than the browser's default of 400, but the hover state is still rendering the browser defaults.

```
.menunav a:hover {font-weight:300;}
```

Edit: The above didn't solve the problem. However, the nav's fixed positioning seems to [introduce a bug](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/position-fixed-font-weight-is-thinner-new-safari-6-1/). Adding "-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;" to the body or html tag will create font consistency.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work :( The hover button in the list affects everything in the <nav>. It shouldn't happen! (I use OS X 10.9.1 - Safari 7.0.1)

Comment: Setting the nav's positioning to fixed seems to [introduce a bug](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/position-fixed-font-weight-is-thinner-new-safari-6-1/). While not a perfect fix, you can add "-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;" to the body or html tag for font consistency.